# Angular2 and medium Editor

Tags: angular, medium-editor

i'm install MediumEditor and angular2-medium-editor, i follow the role who write in the website

https://github.com/codiak/angular2-medium-editor

but when i try to import this:

```
import { MediumEditorDirective } from 'angular2-medium-editor/medium-editor.directive.ts';
```

give me this error cannot import path with .ts, i try also with out .ts but don't work

it s anybody use this editor? why don't work thanks

Thanks for Help!

Comment: up i write i try also without .ts and don't work:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: i clone both medium-editor and angular2-medium-editor and call     import { MediumEditorDirective } from '../angular2-medium-editor/medium-editor.directive';  but the same dont work the error: GET http://localhost:3000/angular2-medium-editor/medium-editor.directive 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Hi, I was facing the same issue so I switched to https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg